# How does DNN (8.5) create a filename for the page cache file?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

How does DNN (8.5) create a filename for the page cache file? I know it creates a separate cache file for each URL variant, based on the query string.

Filenames look like this: 263_48CFC1D52ED8E2193FF112AD73CEC246.data.resources or 263_E6D2BE611E16671022423FEA3D5C0A02.data.resources. I've determined that the part in front of the underscore is the TabID, but what about the rest?

I need to delete specific cache file on demand, targeting only the version of the URL with specific query string. If I delete all files beginning with a specific TabID, I would need to rebuild thousands of variants of that page.

Comment: You may have better luck asking this in the DNN forums.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I've been scouring the DNN forums for days now, no joy :(

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a bit of digging to really uncover this, as the value is a hashed key value based on the parameter etc.

The actual key is created using this: https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/5b9bd693f5ad553f2ce2db7ed7ca92914e585cac/DNN%20Platform/Library/Services/OutputCache/OutputCachingProvider.cs#L125

At the top of that same file, you will see the process that creates the actual Hash for file storage.